# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined at colorguessinggame.js:13

Tags: javascript

I created an array that creates an x amount of RGB colors randomly. I want to take this information and assign each element in the array to a square button. So the idea is when the code is ran each instance, the square buttons will get a new RGB color to it.

```
var generateColors = generateArray(6);
var generateColorOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".colorSquare");

// giving each button a color value from the array
for(var i = 0; i < generateColorOptions.length; i++) {
    generateColors[i].style.background = generateColors[i];
}

//want to make one of the RGB values created the solution RGB that prints in the beiggining
function generateArray(num) {
    var colorArray = [num];

    for(var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        //random color generated
        colorArray.push(generateRGBNumber());
        //want to always push an array element to be the given RGB value
    }

    return colorArray;
}

function generateRGBNumber() {
  var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
  var r = num >> 16;
  var g = num >> 8 & 255;
  var b = num & 255;
  return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are changin background of generateColors function change it to generateColorOptions.
Also decalre colorArray is [] and iterate for loop with num only. not num.length because number is a function. Use below code.

```
var generateColors = generateArray(6);
var generateColorOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".colorSquare");

// giving each button a color value from the array
for (var i = 0; i < generateColorOptions.length; i++) {
    generateColorOptions[i].style.background = generateColors[i];
}

//want to make one of the RGB values created the solution RGB that prints in the beiggining
function generateArray(num) {
    var colorArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //random color generated
        colorArray.push(generateRGBNumber());
        //want to always push an array element to be the given RGB value
    }

    return colorArray;
}

function generateRGBNumber() {
    var num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
    var r = num >> 16;
    var g = num >> 8 & 255;
    var b = num & 255;
    return 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
}
```

Comment: I saw the generate Colors mistake right after i posted this.So why do we not want num to be declared with the array? That kinda stumps me

Comment: It will take num as first element. for e.g. in our cars colorArray = [6] will have 6 as first element and other rgb values will be pushed in second indexes, You can test it and cross verify.